# How to render textview before webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-linearlayout

In below code I'm attempting to render a webview after a textview. The webview renders but the textview appears to be embedded within the webview but does not render.

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sum.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

textview embedded within webview :

[image]

The textview has been added prior to the webview so it should be rendered before the webview instead of within the webview ?

Adding the textview to the framelayout does not also render the textview :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Update :

Using a LinearLayout renders the textview but the webview is not rendering below the textview, instead it's rendered to right :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sum.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

        <WebView
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

How to wrap content after textview ?

Update 2 :

This works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.sum.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />

        <WebView
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `TextView` to be shown over the `WebView`, you should put it after the `WebView` in your layout XML file, like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm attempting to render the textview before the webview

Comment: The you must include the `TextView` and the `WebView` in a `LinearLayout`.

Comment: You should set the LinearLayout orientation attribute to vertical.